# How to make fat-jar with Embedded EJB container

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm trying to create a fat-jar using Embedded EJB container.
My problem is that when I try to run the jar file, IllegalArgumentException occurred.

Please help me.

My Code.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        try (EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer()) {
            String jndi = "java:global/javaee-batch/MainLogic";
            MainLogic logic = (MainLogic) container.getContext().lookup(jndi);
            logic.run();
        }
    }
```

If I can execute by maven, this code is successful.

here are my poms:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>simplebatch</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaEE-Batch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>simplebatch.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-sample-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>     
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I execute "JavaEE-Batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar", this error occurred.

```
Sep 15, 2014 8:21:46 PM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [javaee-batch]
Sep 15, 2014 8:21:46 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle deploy
SEVERE: Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Referencing error: this bundle has no bean of name: MEJBBean
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.getEjbByName(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.getEjbByName(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.node.runtime.EjbNode.setElementValue(EjbNode.java:133)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.endElement(SaxParserHandler.java:617)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLNSDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(XMLNSDTDValidator.java:266)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2005)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:879)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
```

What do I do to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `MEJBBean` part of your beans or an external library? 
The stacktrace is missing more information. There should be at least caused by... There is a likelihood that maven (on whichever ide you use) sets the correct dependency paths, but on building with dependency, this path is not copied, either because this external dependency has scope `provided` or is set as `optional`